# Imprimir por consola un valor de objeto

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy consumiendo una api, que me retorna el nombre, email e imagen de un usuario. Pero al querer imprimir el valor de nombre, me dice undefined.
Esta es la respuesta de la api

```
    const [usuarioi, setusuarioi] = useState([]);
    const obtenerUsuario = async () => {
    const resultado = await fetch(api + email2)
      .then((respuesta) => respuesta.json())
      .then(data => {
        setusuarioi(data)
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    obtenerUsuario();  
  }, []);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy buenas Alan.
Te da problema al acceder al nombre, pero ¿Has probado a imprimir que estas guardando en usuarioi?, ¿Es también undefined?. Ya que quizás no estas accediendo bien al nombre, así comprobamos si realmente esta guardando algo en usuarioi o no. Y si puedes pasa el código de como accedes o imprimes ese valor.

Comment: Buenas, usuarioi esta guardando bien. Lo que utilice para imprimir es, usuarioi para ver todo lo que tiene, y utilice usuarioi.nombre de esta forma es la que me dice undefined

Comment: @AlanGalvan Viendo el log del objeto, la sintaxis correcta debería ser `usuarioi.usuario.nombre`

Answer (score -2):

```
.then((data)=>{
  //Puedes validar si hace la peticion o no,
  if(data.usuario !== undefined){ //o data.main, lo que fuere
    const usuarioArray = {
      email: data.email,
      nombre: data.nombre
      //etc
    };
    setusuarioi(usuarioArray);
    //Aqui puedes usar tambien
    //Por si quieres agregar mas usuarios cada que hagas la peticion
    //setusuarioi(usuarioOld => [...usuarioOld, usuarioArray]);
  } else{
     alert("Usuario no encontrado")
  } 
}
```

Comment: Buenas, intente de esta forma, pero las propiedades de usuaroArray cuando lo imprimo son undefined

Comment: Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Haz clic en [edit] y argumenta tu respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Usa 
usuarioi.usuario.nombre

Comment: @nomikugg por favor agrega una explicación en tus respuestas, revisar [amswer]

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).